# How to set custom object property to filter against in Angular typeahead?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter, angular-ui-typeahead

I am trying to implement a generic typeahead directive. It takes a list of options and a configuration object as attributes. One of the properties of the configuration object is the "label" - what to show the user and how to filter the user's queries. However, I am not able to use this property in my filter expression, as such:

```
 uib-typeahead="option as option[config.label] for option in options | filter:{ config[label] :$viewValue }
```

I get the following error when I try to do this:

```
Syntax Error: Token '[' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 26 of the expression [options | filter:{ config[label] :$viewValue }] starting at [[label] :$viewValue }].
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

`ngOptions` wants to accept an object as a filter.  With the statement below you're trying to create and pass it a dynamic keyed object which can't be accomplished inline how it's currently setup, it's invalid Javscript syntax:

```
... filter:{ config[label] :$viewValue }
```

One way to get around this is to construct the object in your controller and then pass it in to your filter, note I'm referencing the dynamic filter's value by name, not `$viewValue`:

```
// controller
$scope.filterByObj[$scope.config['label']] = $scope.selectedFilter;

// template
... filter: filterByObj
```

I've put together an example that describes this idea: http://plnkr.co/edit/7gffq3mEtFqrfAP4shrj?p=preview